# CMake trouble with Boost 1.58 on Debian Wheezy

Tags: boost, cmake, debian

Debian Wheezy comes with boost 1.49, but i need to use a newer version (>=1.50).
What is the standard way ?
I've installed boost 1.58 to /usr/local, set the BOOST_ROOT to /usr/local, but cmake can't find it, only the old 1.49 in the /usr.
What can i do ?

Comment: Any reason not to remove the old boost? Also how do you look for boost in cmake? If you use FindBoost you can specify a minimum version.

Comment: I don't want to remove the old boost because other packages depends on that. The cmake uses the FindBoost to look for boost, and boost >= 1.50 is really needed (i want to build stromx). In theory i can use "alternative" boost with the method decribed, but it doesn't work for some reason. The problem is that FindBoost looks the old version despite the BOOST_ROOT variable.

Comment: I remember having the same issues a few years ago and having the luxury of being able to remove the old one. I think CMake found the right include files but the wrong libraries, but I could be wrong. The next option would be to tell CMake explicitly where the libraries are, with a series of `find_library(BOOST_REGEX NAMES  boost_regex  PATHS /usr/local/lib`, and something similar for the include files, if necessary. But that won't work that well if other developers use your files in a different environment.

Comment: I've tried to define Boost_LIBRARYDIR, INCLUDEDIR and others, but the problem is that cmake/FindBoost reads the version from /usr/include/boost/version.hpp. Temporary workaround: i've overwritten this version.hpp with the new version (1.58) and everything works fine, uses the new boost from /usr/local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have similar situation on Ubuntu 14.04 - default boost 1.54 installed and my own built boost 1.56.

I have my CMakeLists.txt configured the following way:

```
LIST (APPEND CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH "/usr/local/lib") # make sure there are boost library files
LIST (APPEND CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH "/usr/local/include") # make sure there is a boost directory

FIND_PACKAGE (Boost 1.56 COMPONENTS "system" "filesystem" REQUIRED)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${your_app} ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
```